# Why is proc univariate failing for certain variables?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm calculating 'outliers' for a bunch of numeric variables.

This includes running a proc univariate to calculate the 1st and 3rd quartile as well as the interquartile range and  later using these in a calculation.

The program is getting stuck on two variables and I'm getting **ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory.**

It's working perfectly fine for the rest of ~80 variables which I can run altogether without getting an error.

I have a separate program solely for the two and it just won't work.

any ideas?

I don't think there's anything wrong with the values - I've had a look at minimum and maximum values and they look fine; they are similar to the values of some of the other variables for which the program ran fine.

I've also tried using PROC MEANS which works for these two but I'm getting different values for the quartiles and outliers. I'd rather work out what's going on with PROC UNIVARIATE instead.

Comment: It's possible your computer is under resourced or set to the default of 2/4GB of RAM. Check your memory allocation (https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/proc/n0ptusb2uzaoyln1bm33yr43trex.htm)

Comment: PROC UNIVARIATE does a LOT more work than PROC MEANS.  If all you want is percentiles, PROC MEANS should be more efficient.  Can you show your PROC UNIVARIATE code and PROC MEANS code that give different values for Q1 and Q3? That's surprising, unless you're overriding the default percentile definitions.